# Centered marker on polyline

Tags: android, marker

I am animating a marker between two points. I also drew a polyline between two points.

I want my marker to be centered on the polyline. But my custom icon is not placed at the center of the polyline as shown in the below picture.

How do I get the marker centered on the polyline?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: for future questions: it's simpler for others when you post your code not only bug image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`anchor` property is what you're looking for

```
static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.90, 115.86);
Marker perth = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(PERTH)
                      .anchor(0.5,0.5))
```

`(0.5,0,5)` means that your marker will be pinned at the middle of your marker image. for better understanding of this `(0.0,0.0)` means left top corner of your image and (1.0,1.0) means bottom right corner. Default is `(0.5,1.0)` middle of bottom edge that's why your markers looks like this.

from docs:

> The anchor point is specified in the continuous space [0.0, 1.0] x
>   [0.0, 1.0], where (0, 0) is the top-left corner of the image, and (1,
>   1) is the bottom-right corner. The anchoring point in a W x H image is
>   the nearest discrete grid point in a (W + 1) x (H + 1) grid, obtained
>   by scaling the then rounding. For example, in a 4 x 2 image, the
>   anchor point (0.7, 0.6) resolves to the grid point at (3, 1).

[source](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setAnchor(float,%20float))

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. It working by adding anchor 
`.anchor(0.5f,0.5f)`